# Cypress - How to wait for XHR request

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm a beginner to Cypress. I'm sure it is a simple question and I already read the documentation of Cypress, but something still seems to wrong in my Cypress test. I want to wait for an `xhr` request to be finished, when I click on a different language of the page I want to test.

It works, when I use `wait(5000)`, but I think, there is a better way to wait for the `xhr` request to be finished than fix wait 5 secs.
This is my code:

```
describe('test',() => {
    it('should open homepage, page "history", click on English language, click on German language',() => {
        cy.server();
        cy.route('POST','/ajax.php').as('request');
        cy.visit('http://localhost:1234/history');
        cy.wait('@request');
        cy.get('div[class="cursorPointer flagSelect flag-icon-gb"]').click({force:true});
        cy.route('POST','/ajax.php').as('request');
        cy.wait(['@request']);
        //cy.wait(5000); // <- this works, but seems to be not the best way
        cy.get('h2').should(($res) => {
            expect($res).to.contain('History');
        })
        cy.get('.dataContainer').find('.container').should('have.length', 8);
    });
});
```

The last check

```
cy.get('.dataContainer').find('.container').should('have.length', 8);
```

is not successful, because the `xhr` request is not yet finished.
The `xhr` request is being fired, when the click on the icon is done:

```
cy.get('div[class="cursorPointer flagSelect flag-icon-gb"]').click({force:true});
```

Here an image of the xhr request, if that helps to find the error:

[image]

Comment: At what point is the test not successful? Does it fail on the `cy.wait(['@request'])` or does it fail on `cy.get('h2').should(($res) => {`? Have you tried running the test headfull? The testrunner provides information of which call has been mocked and got an alias, and it shows for which alias it waits for. Those two point can give you more information.

Comment: It fails at `cy.get('.dataContainer').find('.container').should('have.length', 8);`, because the data is not loaded at this time. It does not wait for the request to complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that this line is correct? Otherwise the cy.wait won't function as you want.

```
cy.route('POST','/ajax.php').as('request');
```

I expect something like

```
cy.route('GET','/endpoint').as('request');
```

You can lookup what route is it via developer tools (F12 in Chrome). 
Go to network to monitor what kind of XHRs load when you open your page.

[Find out request URL and Method - example with bing.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jBGL.png)

Also:
I prefer to include the cy.server() and cy.route() command in the beforeEach.
Then you only need the cy.wait() in the test itself.
See https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#2-Run-shared-code-before-each-test for more information about that.

Comment: I've added an screenshot of the `xhr` request. I assume that this is correct.

Comment: I added a screenshot to make sure you have the correct request URL and method.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I needed define the full url with `http://.../ajax.php` as route. Then it works fine! Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you should do like that:

```
describe('test',() => { //no here async mode
    it('should open homepage, page "history", click on English language, click on German language', async () => { //but here
        cy.server();
        cy.route('POST','/ajax.php').as('request').as('requestToWait); // as-construction
        const requestToWait = await cy.wait('@requestToWait');//here we are waiting and getting response object
        // any other code
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but this does not work. error message is: `Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function (6:30)`. I've also tried to install the npm package `https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-promise`, but the error is the same.

Comment: oh, sorry, I put down `async` in wrong way, but now I've edited my solution - have a look

Comment: Cypress won't support "async/await" by design, see the "Why can’t I use async / await?" section [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress.html#Commands-Are-Asynchronous).